# How to change the string input coming from parent LWC to Date format in child LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I'm having a parent LWC from where I'm passing a deliveryYear value to Child LWC

In parent I'm getting deliveryYear as 2023/2024 from which I'm splitting the first year and sending to child.

[image]

Parent.js

```
var del = this.deliveryYear.split("/");
this.splitDelYear = del[0];
```

Parent.html

```
<c-child deliveryyear={splitDelYear}></c-child>
```

In child LWC I'm capturing this value and trying to build a min and max date range from it. Used this date range in my html but it is not throwing error when selecting date outside this range.

Child.js

```
@api deliveryyear;

delyearstartdate;
delyearenddate;
delyearenddate=new Date(this.deliveryyear1+1,8,30);
delyearstartdate = new Date(this.deliveryyear1,9,1);
startdatemin=this.formatDate(this.delyearstartdate);
enddatemax=this.formatDate(this.delyearenddate);
```

Child.html

```
<lightning-input type="date" onchange={handleChange}  class="selector" min={startdatemin} disabled={disabled} ></lightning-input>

<lightning-input type="date" onchange={handleChange}  class="selector" min={enddatemax} disabled={disabled} ></lightning-input>
```

This is working fine if I'm hard-coding a value for deliveryyear in child component itself

child.js

```
deliveryyear1=2023;

delyearstartdate;
delyearenddate;
delyearenddate=new Date(this.deliveryyear1+1,8,30);
delyearstartdate = new Date(this.deliveryyear1,9,1);
startdatemin=this.formatDate(this.delyearstartdate);
enddatemax=this.formatDate(this.delyearenddate);
```

[image]

Any inputs on why it is not formatting the value that is coming from parent component.

Both are showing same result when printed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself. So instead of splitting the year in the parent split the year in child and then convert it into integer to format it as required.

child.js:
`@api this.deliveryyear` (which is "2023/2024")

In connected call back I handled the split and date conversion

```
        var del = this.deliveryyear.split("/");
        this.splitDelYear = Number(del[0]);
        this.delyearenddate=new Date(this.splitDelYear+1,8,30);
        this.delyearstartdate = new Date(this.splitDelYear,9,1);
        this.startdatemin=this.formatDate(this.delyearstartdate);
        this.enddatemax=this.formatDate(this.delyearenddate);
```